# How to submit jars stored in AWS S3 to Local Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-submit

**Question**:  How to submit jars stored in AWS S3 to Local Spark?

I'm looking for a way to submit jars stored in S3 to Local Spark (not EMR).
However, when I investigated this, I only see how to submit it to the EMR Spark Cluster.

The closest answer to the method I've been looking for is in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60900601/how-to-submit-a-spark-job-of-which-the-jar-is-hosted-in-s3-object-store).
However, the answer above seems to only work with EMR. (Isn't it? I may be wrong.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spark documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management) says:

> Spark uses the following URL scheme to allow different strategies for
> disseminating jars:
>
> **file**: - Absolute paths and file:/ URIs are served by the driver’s HTTP
> file server, and every executor pulls the file from the driver HTTP
> server.
>
> **hdfs:, http:, https:, ftp:** - these pull down files and JARs
> from the URI as expected
>
> **local**: - a URI starting with local:/ is
> expected to exist as a local file on each worker node.

So, as long as your s3 bucket is public and you can access it using URI, you can specify one of the above mentioned